# Weird character at start of json content type

Tags: json, character

I'm trying to return json content read from MySQL server. This is supposed to be easy but, there is a 'weird' character that keeps appearing at start of the content.

I have two pages for returning content:

1. [kcb433.sytes.net/as/test.php?json=true&limit=6&input=d](http://kcb433.sytes.net/as/test.php?json=true&limit=6&input=d)

   this test.php is from a script written by Timothy Groves, which converts an array to json output
2. http://kcb433.sytes.net/k.php?k=4

   this one is supposed to do the same

I tried to validate it here [jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com) but just page 1 gets validated, page 2 says that it does not contain JSON data.

If accessed directly both pages has no problems. Then what is the difference, why both don't get validated?

Then I found this page [jsonformat.com](http://jsonformat.com) and tried the same thing. Page 1 was ok and page 2 wasn't but, surprisingly the data could be read. At a glance,

```
{"a":"b"}
```

may look good but there is a character in front.

According to a hex editor online, this is the value of the string above (instead of 9 values, there are 10):

```
-- 7B 22 61 22 3A 22 62  22 7D
```

The code to echo json in page 2 is:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo "{\"a\":\"b\"}";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `k.php` file has [BOM signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the start, save `k.php` again with UTF8 without BOM.

Comment: I was in the process of typing this, just too slow!  Would like to add: the BOM is easily visible with Fiddler, which has a built-in hex viewer.

Comment: Which editor you using to edit php file? I noticed that Notepad does not have option for `UTF-8 without BOM`. In Notepad++, you could easily choose `UTF-8 without BOM` encoding easily.

Comment: I'm using dreamweaver and it has that option but it also has Unicode Normalization Forms option. I'm going to try notepad++

Comment: wow! Notepad++ is the best! UTF-8 without BOM, clicked and working. Thanks S.Mark