# Backbone.js Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'id' in etc to copy json data

Tags: json, backbone.js

I have a backbone.js error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'id' in
>   {"websiteID":"2","title":"titre site 2"} backbone-min.js:9

I am trying to copy json data (received from ajax) into an instance of a Model.

How can I fix this problem?

My code is:

```
var Website = Backbone.Model.extend({
    // set default json data in the website:
    defaults: {"websiteID":"1","title":"default title"}
});

var website = new Website();

function UpdateWebsiteBasedOnDBData() {
  this.url = 'script.php';
}

UpdateWebsiteBasedOnDBData.prototype.readData = function(dataToGet) {
        return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: this.url,
        data: dataToGet,
        context: this,
        success: this.onSuccess
      });
};

UpdateWebsiteBasedOnDBData.prototype.onSuccess = function(data) {
    website.set(data);
    alert( website.get("websiteID") );
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    var updateWebsiteBasedOnDBData = new UpdateWebsiteBasedOnDBData();
    updateWebsiteBasedOnDBData.readData({"websiteID": 2});
});
```

The script.php returns proper json:

{"websiteID":"2","title":"titre site 2"}

---

**Update**:

I still need to check but I strongly suspect my json to actually not be valid.
Root cause could be (still to be verified) the character set of my php script.

Related: [Weird character at start of json content type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475113/weird-character-at-start-of-json-content-type)

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue [check the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fguillen/6G4Aq/) even if I wrap the `data` as an string. Can you fork my jsFiddle and reproduce the issue? Which is the real line _of your code_ that produces the error? (follow the error backtrace until find one line of your code)

Comment: As @JayC said... which version of Backbone are you using?

Comment: @fguillen Thanks for the jsfiddle. I am using underscore.js/1.1.4 and backbone.js/0.3.3. But I suspect I have a problem with my Json data. I think my PHP script is messing my json.

Comment: For God's sake, update! :) `underscore.js/1.3.3` and `backbone.js/0.9.2` if not you will find your self alone with your issues

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to guess you have to name the identity field for your model.

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-idAttribute

But I'm not quite sure from the code you posted that the issue is located there.  I've used models without ids in the past, IIRC, as for certain models, I just wanted to implement readonly view/search functionality, not CRUD functionality, and the identities were not important in those scenarios....  (This was before the current version of Backbone.js, though, and I could be completely off my noggin about that...)