# Android - Convert JSON to UFT-8

Tags: android, json, utf-8

I need help converting JSON response to UTF-8. 
Everything worked perfectly when i had saved my .json file with UTF-8 (without BOM). When I saved the file with only UTF-8 it would not work, the app crashes while getting JSON now.

Logcat at bottom

The source:

```
..

    public class JSONPARSER extends ListActivity {


        private static String url = "http://profusum.se/neger.json";


        private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "messages";
        private static final String TAG_NAME = "namn";
        private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
        private static final String TAG_KIK = "facebook";
        private static final String TAG_IMGURL = "img";


        JSONArray contacts = null;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.drivers);


            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

            try {


                contacts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);


                    contactList.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item,
                    new String[] { TAG_NAME,}, new int[] {
                            R.id.inboxName, });

            setListAdapter(adapter);

            ListView lv = getListView();

            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.inboxName)).getText().toString();

                    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),                 SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
                    startActivity(in);

                }
            });



        }
}
```

I've searched hard for this now, my guess it's simple..but I can't figure it out.

```
05-01 21:13:08.213: E/JSON Parser(27153): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value ï»¿ of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

**Summary**

When i save the file with "UTF-8 (without BOM)" in Notepad++ the parsing is successful. But I get these weird symbols in the app.(see example)

But when I save the file with "UTF-8" in Notepad++ the JSON gives me the correct symbols, but the Android app won't parse it.

```
Example
Tim BillstrÃ¶m
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [RFC 4627](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) the default encoding should for JSON is UTF-8. And [UTF-8 doesn't *need* a BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) and it's actually discouraged (strictly speaking: "Use of a BOM is neither required nor recommended for UTF-8")!

So what you should do is to save your file as "UTF-8 (without BOM)" (which should really be the default and "UTF-8 (with BOM)" should be the special option.

If you're using the `JSONParser` class [from this blog post](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) (or something similar), then you should fix that code: It hard-codes the ISO-8859-1 encoding, which is **wrong** (unless you specifically know that you need that).

Ideally you should respect the encoding that the server tells you in the HTTP headers. Alternatively you could assume the specified default (which is UTF-8).

Comment: Oh, I forgot to change from "iso-8859-1" to "utf-8". Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @TimLilleSkuttBillström: you're welcome. In the future please mention any third-party libraries/classes you use (as there's no `JSONParser` class in the Android API).

Answer (score 0):

You should use JSON with UTF-8 encoding without BOM, otherwise you get these strange characters at the beginning of the file, and that you cannot parse it.

Also see [this question (about PHP but same kind of issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475113/weird-character-at-start-of-json-content-type).

Comment: I've edited the question, look at the bottom. Thanks in advance